# Eigenvector with a matrix 3x3 where column 3 and row 3 become null with the eigenvalue.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrix:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
        \frac{3}{2} & \frac{-1}{2} & 0 \\
        \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)$$

I have found the eigenvalues $1, 2$ and $3$. Can someone tell me what is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $=3$?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(0,0,1)^T$ does it...........